# Joining Form fields with Bootstrap 3 possible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to construct a date field unsuccessfully,which will put day month and Year together side by side as if it is a one field. Instead they stack on top of each other. If I add columns there will be a massive gap between which isn't desirable. I've been able to set it nicely with tables, but that's not a very semantic approach.

Can you help with an elegant solution?

```
<form action="/login" method="post" role="form" data-parsley-validate="">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group"> 
                      <label for="i_am_a">i_am_a_lbl</label>
                      <select id="i_am_a" class="form-control">
                        <option value="man">man</option>
                        <option value="woman">woman</option>
                      </select>
                      <!-- input(id=field._id, placeholder=field._id).margin10p.form-control.input-lg-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
          <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="looking_for">looking_for_lbl</label>
                      <select id="looking_for" class="form-control">
                        <option value="women">women</option>
                        <option value="men">men</option>
                      </select>
                      <!-- input(id=field._id, placeholder=field._id).margin10p.form-control.input-lg-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
          <div class="form-group">
                      <select id="date_of_birth" width="20" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Day</option>
                        <option value="0">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                        <option value="2">3 ... removed the rest</option>
                      </select>
                      <select id="date_of_birth" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Month</option>
                        <option value="january">January</option>
                        <option value="february">February</option>
                        <option value="march.. other months">March</option>
                      </select>
                      <select id="date_of_birth" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Year</option>
                        <option value="1997">1998</option>
                        <option value="1996">1997</option>
                        <option value="1995">1996...</option>
                      </select>
                      <!-- input(id=field._id, placeholder=field._id).margin10p.form-control.input-lg-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">titiki putike dzerq tveq</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this in overriding css :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/123358

**CSS** :

```
.datetimer .form-control{
    width : 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

**HTML** :

```
<div class="col-md-12"> 
  <div class="form-group datetimer">
              <select id="date_of_birth" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Day</option>
                <option value="0">1</option>
                <option value="1">2</option>
                <option value="2">3 ... removed the rest</option>
              </select>
              <select id="date_of_birth" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Month</option>
                <option value="january">January</option>
                <option value="february">February</option>
                <option value="march.. other months">March</option>
              </select>
              <select id="date_of_birth" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Year</option>
                <option value="1997">1998</option>
                <option value="1996">1997</option>
                <option value="1995">1996...</option>
              </select>
              <!-- input(id=field._id, placeholder=field._id).margin10p.form-control.input-lg-->
  </div>
</div>
```